# managing sprite kit multiplayer world node

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I've been working on a 'side scroller' sprite kit game (not really side scroller, you can move in any direction) and the apple docs/stackoverflow answers say to make a world node as the child of the scene, and move the world node instead of the character sprite.

does this suggestion change for a multiplayer game where there are multiple character sprites moving inside the same world node? Because in this case, one sprite moving changes the world for everybody.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion still applies in multiplayer. Normally you have only one local player, so the "camera" will still be following that particular player and none other.

In local multiplayer (2 players playing on same device) you would probably have the camera follow the mid point between the two players. But it's still the same principle.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I'd like to know a bit more detail, it's my first time making a game so I'm not very knowledgable. Or maybe you have a link to a tutorial or article?

Comment: Also, what if the world is very large, and the two players are far apart that the camera isnt big enough to show both. Then having the camera in the middle point wouldn't work right?

Comment: yes, in that case you would have to dusallow them to move further apart (not as simple as it sounds). but you only need this in local multiplayer (both playing onnsame device), in "regular" multiplaxer it's okay if other players leave the local player's viewable area.

Comment: yea that's what I meant, its not on the same device, its connecting through Game Center or something like that, from 2 separate devices. what happens in this case? How should the camera behave? Do I still move the world, or do I move the "camera" for each player